# shared_ptr and const methods thread-safety

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, shared-ptr

Assume that we have a `class A` with const methods(only).

```
class A
{
public:
    void method1() const;
    void method2() const;
}
```

Also, we have another `class B` that has `shared_ptr` of `class A` and also methods that return it and change it with mutex protection:

```
class B
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> ptr;
    std::mutex m;
public:
    B()
    {
        ptr = std::make_shared<A>();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<A> getPtr() const
    {
        mutex_on_stack mut(m);
        return ptr;
    }

    void resetPtr()
    {
        mutex_on_stack mut(m);
        ptr.reset(new A());
    }
}
```

`ptr` variable is protected by mutexes, so I assume that it is thread-safe. But I am not sure about the safety of inner object itself.

```
B objB;

//thread 1
auto p1 = objB->getPtr();
p1->method1(); //calling const method

//thread 2
auto p2 = objB->getPtr();
p2->method2(); //calling const method

//thread 3
objB->resetPtr();
```

Threads 1 and 2 call `getPtr()` method and increase reference counter of `shared_ptr` as it copied. So I think that inner pointer will not be accidently deleted there by `resetPtr()` in thread 3. Also, methods `method1` and `method2` are const so it does not modify inner object. But I can be wrong.

So I have two questions:

1. Is the code above thread-safe?
2. Is the `class A` thread-safe at all?

Comment: What is `mutex_on_stack`?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments below `mutex_on_stack` is a holder that locks mutex on the creation and unlocks it on the destroy. Holder lives only in the current scope so mutex will be unlocked at the method end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `A` is thread safe because it only uses `const` functions, which may be assumed to not alter the externally visible state. While `const` functions are capable of *modifying* internal state if the class also has `mutable` members, it's common to assume any `mutable` members are synchronized so two concurrent readers of an object will never encounter race conditions.

---

Accesses to the contents of a `shared_ptr` are thread safe, and in fact don't even require the additional synchronization of the mutex. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr):

> All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment)
>   can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr
>   without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies
>   and share ownership of the same object.

However, this only holds if you're not calling non-`const` functions of the `shared_ptr` in question:

> If multiple threads of execution access the same shared_ptr without
>   synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member
>   function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur; the shared_ptr
>   overloads of atomic functions can be used to prevent the data race.

So class `B` wouldn't be quite thread-safe right now without the mutex, because you're calling `reset` on the function. It would be made thread-safe without the mutex if instead of calling `reset` you used the [atomic overloads for `shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic).

As it is, the only thing you need to do to ensure thread safety is ensure your RAII wrapper lasts until the end of the function scope, which it is doing.

On the topic of the RAII wrapper, you don't need to roll your own lock-unlock mechanism. The standard library already supplies RAII locks for you, in the form of [`lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard), [`unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) and [`shared_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock). A simple scenario like this would probably match best with `lock_guard`, which is designed to function as a simple scoped lock.

Comment: So if I call non-const methods of `shared_ptr` (such as `reset`) it will lead to race conditions. But I have mutex protection around it right now. So it has to be ok even without atomics, no?

Comment: @MykolaNiemtsov if you don't use the atomic overloads, yes. That is my understanding.

Comment: "on different instances" seems to be a pretty important point. It is decidedly *not* correct for two threads to make a copy of the *same* shared pointer.

Comment: @jaggedSpire He's fine. All accesses to `ptr` are protected by a mutex. (Assuming `mutex_on_stack` is an RAII mutex holder.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, `mutex_on_stack` is RAII mutex holder.

Comment: @MykolaNiemtsov: How long does it live for? :-)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: It obviously gets destroyed after scope ends. In the end of the method.

Comment: @MykolaNiemtsov that expression returns a temporary, it looks like. Its lifetime ends at the end of the full-expression in that case.

Comment: Hmmm. from cppreference again: "To satisfy thread safety requirements, the reference counters are typically incremented using an equivalent of std::atomic::fetch_add with std::memory_order_relaxed (decrementing requires release-acquire ordering to safely destroy the control block)." so it seems like without the mutex of dubious lifetime, reference counting is fine, unless I'm reading that badly

Comment: @jaggedSpire: I talked about `mutex_on_stack`, not about returned value. As long as it is not returned by reference outside it should be destroyed at the and of the method. Am I right?

Comment: @MykolaNiemtsov it needs to be stored in a variable with a lifetime the length of the scope you want. The easiest way would be to bind the returned value to a reference.

Comment: If you did that then the destructor would execute at the end of the scope after the call to `reset` rather than after the end of the full-expression before the call to `reset`

Comment: Sorry, I can not see the problem with mutex as it is right now:(
Also,according to @DavidSchwartz comment, It looks like the class B is thread-safe after all.
Or I miss something? If not, can you edit the answer and I will accept it as "correct".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111562/discussion-between-mykola-niemtsov-and-jaggedspire).

Comment: @MykolaNiemtsov: If you make your constructors and destructors print diagnostic messages, you can see for yourself in which order they execute.